# Why is Debian Wheezy not displaying desktop icons?

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop

After freshly installing Debian with Gnome 3, I cannot enable desktop icons.

I tried to use `dconf-editor`, but all values were locked. I tried `sudo dconf-editor`: The option was changeable but had no effect... I also tried `gnome-tweak-tool` and to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo dconf-editor` changes the settings of the root user, not the normal user.

Comment: Your file manager seems to not have control over your desktop. Get gconf editor. I think it has an option to enable file manager control over desktop.

Comment: In gconf-editor I don't have any keys. The keys tree is only `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have at least one of these packages: `tango-icon-theme`, `hicolor-icon-theme` or `gnome-icon-theme`.

Comment: I'll check and answer in few hours

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, i need 50 reputation points to be able to comment in other posts... so...

Comment: I have no idea how this is "not an answer", if all you need to do is install one of those packages to fix it

Comment: @fgbreel But on the other hand I think that problem is not in missing icons packages but rather in permissions. I just can't change values in dconf-editor

Comment: Try to run `dpkg-reconfigure hicolor-icon-theme` for example. dpkg always provides in auto mode a set of packages as default for a specific purpose using (Ex: `update-alternatives --query editor`) command show some packages who provides editor, but i don't know what is the string to query to show for icons. After changing the alternative for icons, you need to rebuild icons cache with `update-icon-caches` or `gtk-update-icon-caches`, i don't tested if these last commands work with gnome3.

Answer (score 2):

whoa.............. a question that I actually  know the answer to.  :)

```
sudo dconf-editor
```

org/gnome/desktop/background --- and check the box to show the desktop icons.

Comment: make sure you are sudo su to open the editor.  Have root access.

Comment: I suggest that you indent your command by 4 spaces (for better formatting), remove the first sentence, remove your signature (your username is already displayed below the anser) and that you integrate your command into the answer.

Comment: this is what worked for me